# Remove comments from JSON data

Tags: php, regex, json, comments

I need to remove all `/*...*/` style comments from JSON data. How do I do it with regular expressions so that string values like this

```
{
    "propName": "Hello \" /* hi */ there."
}
```

remain unchanged?

Comment: Did you know StackOverflow has a `search` function? [Check This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581049/preg-replace-out-css-comments)

Comment: [This is all you need](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1581063/1438393)

Comment: @MihaiIorga Doesn't work for `"prop0": /* comment */ "Hello"` comments.

Comment: @AmalMurali Same thing.

Comment: @DesmondHume why don't you at least try? `$code = preg_replace('#/\*(?:.(?!/)|[^\*](?=/)|(?<!\*)/)*\*/#s', '', $code);`

Comment: @MihaiIorga The code you suggest modifies the string value if the value contains `/*...*/`

Comment: You want to remove comments but value to remain the same? Impossible or I don't understand

Comment: @MihaiIorga Moreover, comments like this `"propName": "Hello", /* comment */` aren't removed either with the code in the accepted answer.

Comment: @MihaiIorga Yep that's what I need, it's in the question actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must first avoid all the content that is inside double quotes using the backtrack control verbs *SKIP* and *FAIL* (or a capture)

```
$string = <<<'LOD'
{
    "propName": "Hello \" /* don't remove **/ there." /*this must be removed*/
}
LOD;

$result = preg_replace('~"(?:[^\\\"]+|\\\.)*+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|/\*(?:[^*]+|\*+(?!/))*+\*/~s', '',$string);

// The same with a capture:

$result = preg_replace('~("(?:[^\\\"]+|\\\.)*+")|/\*(?:[^*]+|\*+(?!/))*+\*/~s', '$1',$string);
```

**Pattern details:**

```
"(?:[^\\\"]+|\\\.)*+"
```

This part describe the possible content inside quotes:

```
"              # literal quote
(?:            # open a non-capturing group
    [^\\\"]+   # all characters that are not \ or "
  |            # OR
    \\\.)*+    # escaped char (that can be a quote)
"
```

Then You can make this subpattern fails with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` or `(*SKIP)(?!)`. The *SKIP* forbid the backtracking before this point if the pattern fails after. *FAIL* forces the pattern to fail. Thus, quoted part are skipped (and can't be in the result since you make the subpattern fail after).

Or you use a capturing group and you add the reference in the replacement pattern.

```
/\*(?:[^*]+|\*+(?!/))*+\*/
```

This part describe content inside comments.

```
/\*           # open the comment
(?:           
    [^*]+     # all characters except *
  |           # OR
    \*+(?!/)  # * not followed by / (note that you can't use 
              # a possessive quantifier here)
)*+           # repeat the group zero or more times
\*/           # close the comment
```

The s modifier is used here only when a backslash is before a newline inside quotes.

Comment: But I can't apply `json_decode` to a JSON that contains comments. JSON standard doesn't allow for any comments, yet comment are widely used in JSON files and data.

Comment: Ain't working, neither of the methods. Seem to be affected by `\"`, which should be completely ignored.

Comment: @DesmondHume: I have tested the code and it works well. I advise you to test the code as it is written. I think that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: See for yourself http://ideone.com/K8i4jg `/* don't remove **/` gets removed while isn't supposed to.

Comment: @DesmondHume: Ok, It's because I have forgotten to use triple backslashes. I will correct it.

Comment: Working nice now. Could you please also describe what's going on in the regex?

Comment: Thank you so much. SKIP & FAIL are gonna remain mystery to me though.

Comment: You must first understand what is the backtracking, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html and pages about possessive quantifiers and atomic groups. After take a look at http://pcre.org/pcre.txt

Comment: Oh do you think that `\\\{2}` can be removed since its case is covered by `\\\.`?

Comment: @DesmondHume: sorry you was right, no need to use `\\\{2}`. I have corrected my answer.